# JavaScript dynamically updating total and quantity totals

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For some reason when I update the quantity the total price changes to the total price of which every input I choose. The price won't update properly in the different subtotals either, the second one thinks it is 29.95. And then I can't get the quantity to update properly either. Here is a demo I'm using: http://jsfiddle.net/656arnLy/

```
<body>
<input type="number" min="0" class=" qty form-control" id="quantity">
<input type="text" class="price form-control" id="price" value="29.95" readonly>
<input type="text" class="subtotal form-control" id="subTotal">
<br>
<input type="number" min="0" class=" qty form-control" id="quantity">
<input type="text" class="price form-control" id="price" value="2.99" readonly>
<input type="text" class="subtotal form-control" id="subTotal">
<br>Total Price:
<input type="text" readonly class="totalPrice" id="total">
<br>Total qty:
<input type="text" readonly class="totalQty" id="total">
```

```
$(function () {
$(".qty").change(function () {
    var qty = $(this).hasClass('qty') ? $(this).val() : $(this).siblings('.qty').val();
    var price = $(this).hasClass('price') ? $(this).val() : $(this).siblings('.price').val();
    price = price || 0;
    qty = qty || 0;
    var subtotal = price >= 1 && qty >= 1 ? parseFloat(price * qty) : 0;
    $(this).siblings('.subtotal').val(subtotal);
    var totalPrice = 0;
    var totalQty = 0;
    var update = false;
    $('.subtotal').each(function () {
        subtotal = parseFloat($(this).val()) | 0;
        totalPrice = subtotal ? (parseFloat(totalPrice + subtotal)) : totalPrice;
    });
    $('.qty').each(function () {
        qty = $(this).val();
        totalQty += qty;
    });
    $('.totalPrice').val(totalPrice);
    $('.totalQty').val(totalQty);
});
```

Update: I got the total to work correctly, I just can't get the quantity to work. And are there ways to get around using  so I can put this code for each row in a table??

Updated site: http://jsfiddle.net/656arnLy/14/

Comment: can't repeat IDs on input

Answer (score 0):

Just scanning through your code, several of your input boxes have the same id value. You have two inputs with id value "quantity", 2 with id value price and so on. You definitely do not want to do this. This can cause all sorts of issues. Also, you're updating all inputs that have classname .subtotal in the $(this).siblings line.

Give your inputs different id values, and select the id you want to update and you'll be closer to what you want.

Comment: I got the total to work by adding a div and separating through that but eventually these will be a row in a table and I won't be able to use a div. I still can't get the quantity to update correctly. Its doing concatenation rather than adding it. I've update the site: http://jsfiddle.net/656arnLy/14/

Comment: If numbers are concantenating instead of adding, that means your numbers are actually strings. You will need to convert the string into a number by using parseInt. Also it's a good idea to validate your numbers to make sure they are actually numbers.